# Custom events not being tracked in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, event-tracking

Here is the script I'm using, copied directly from Google:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-CODE']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

    function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
        try {
          var myTracker=_gat._getTrackerByName();
          _gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', category ,  action ]);
          setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100);
        }catch(err){}
    }
</script>
```

And here is the link I'm trying to track:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/" target="_blank" class="ad" onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'Visited website.com');return false;"></a>
```

Yet nothing has shown up in my events report for the last 3 days. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's problems with [Google's Outbound links tracking example](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920)

Assuming you're only using one tracker (which it looks like in your code), the following will work:

```
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
    try {
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category ,  action ]);
      setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100);
    }catch(err){}
}
```